# Bulk rename complexType elements in JAX binding file, i.e. bindings.xjb?

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, cxf

I am working with an external 3rd party WSDL file and trying to generate Java code from it.

The WSDL contains name conflictions between `<s:element>` and `<s:complexType>`. For example:

```xml
      <s:element name="Foo"> <!-- name conflict -->
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SoapMessage" type="tns:Foo" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="Foo"> <!-- name conflict -->
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="tns:SoapMessageBase">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Request" type="tns:FooRequest" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Response" type="tns:FooResponse" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
```

I know that with correct `bindings.jxb`, one of them can be renamed. This is the exact problem described in [named the s:element and s:complexType the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514814/named-the-selement-and-scomplextype-the-same-name)

However，the solution from the post above does not really work. There are a LOT, like 100+, name conflictions in the WSDL.

Before I craft a `bindings.xjb` to resolve every single of them. (Yes, I could write a script), is there any simpler way to address this? Like pattern matching + bulk renaming?

## Update

By far what I can find is to use `<jaxb:nameXmlTransform>` per [Issue with JAXB: nameXmlTransform typeName prefix not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685003/issue-with-jaxb-namexmltransform-typename-prefix-not-working)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
      <jaxb:schemaBindings>
         <jaxb:package name="com.mycompany.hi"/>
         <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:typeName prefix="Hi_"/>
            <jaxb:elementName prefix="Hi_"/>
         </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
      </jaxb:schemaBindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But the challenge is `<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">` - The external WSDL provider does not give any `.xsd` file at all.

Is this a common scenario where only WSDL is provided? or is it just me missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `schemaLocation="./services.wsdl#types1"` solved the problem. Now I can generate code from WSDL without XSD.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="./services.wsdl#types1">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type" />
                <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element" />
            </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```